# Azure Data Factory rest api to SQL causing server violation error

Tags: sql, json, azure-data-factory, rest

I am accessing an api with a token in data factory and I want to load the data into a SQL table. This has worked once or twice, but most of the times, I get this error:

> The server committed a protocol violation.

I know that the api spends some time processing before delivering me anything, but the same get request takes 7 minutes in postman canary, but times out in data factory.

Is there some extra headers or something I should use?

I have set request timeout to 1 hour, but it does not help.

In my opinion, data factory should be able to do the same as in postman canary.

Answer (score 1):

In case your API resides in a private network, you will need to use an Azure Data Factory self-hosted runtime with connectivity to that same private network.

When you execute postman, in your machine, you might be already in same network as the API.

Azure data Factory is a multi tenant service, it has public connectivity, the default runtime uses public network, but to connect with private resources it has the requirement I mentioned earlier.

The API might have been updated and it's requiring different headers.

Please check with API provider, ask them to check logs and see what's missing.

Without further details it's hard to help you.

Hope I gave you enough for a solution.